# Avoid calling unnecessary header

Tags: c++, cmake

Im building a simple C++ shared library called `testlib` and want to test it on a simple runtime environment.
**Library consists of:**

- One header file `include/lib_header.hpp`
- One src file `src/lib_src.cpp`
- headers only 3rdparty library file `3rdparty/dependency_header.hpp`

My Cmake for the library looks like this:

```
project(testlib)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")

add_library(testlib SHARED src/lib_src.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include 
                                           PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdparty)
```

**nb**:

- The header file `include/lib_header.hpp` calls the `3rdparty/dependency_header.hpp`\
- In my particular situation I need to first build the library then call the binary `testlib.so` for linux.\

**Runtime consists of**
single `main.cpp` calling the library. Cmake looks as follows:

```
project(runtime)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(LIBDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/testlib CACHE STRING "headers")
set(BINDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/testlib/build CACHE STRING ".so folder")
set(INCLUDE_DIRS 
        ${LIBDIR}/include
        # ${LIBDIR}/3rdparty/ 
        )
add_library(testlib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(testlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${HORIZON_BIN_DIR}/libtestlib.so)

add_executable(test_runnable src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_runnable PUBLIC testlib)
target_include_directories(test_runnable PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

**Question**: Is there a way to avoid including the `3rdparty` folder in the main file?
As you can see, Im currently commenting the inclusion which leads to `No such file or directory`error.

In the library CMake, tried the following configutations:

1. setting the `3rdparty` as a private header

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include 
                                           PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdparty)
```

2. building the library as `STATIC` instead of `SHARED`

Comment: Sure.   Have your "main file" only use things (types, functions, etc) that are part of your library, but not part of the "3rd party library".    Then your "main file" only needs to include the header for your library, and doesn't need to include any header from the 3rd party library.   Your library header then should not include the 3rd party header.   Your library source file will need to include both its own header and the 3rd party header, if it is to use any 3rd party types or functions.

Comment: PIMPL and forward declarations may help eliminate the include dependency out of the public header: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Comment: show the `#include`s in your `test_runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you’ll have to do is have the library link the third party library privately, then add the library to the project basically, instead of getting the runtime project include both the 3rd party library and your library, get your library to include the 3rd party library, then get the project to include the library, which won’t share dependencies marked private with the project.

Comment: Hey, 

Just to clarify: The main file only calls the ` lib_header.hpp` and not the `dependency_header.hpp`
I tried setting the 3rd party as a private lib, however the same error still persists. My understanding is that:
- main file calls `lib_header.hpp`
- `lib_header.hpp` calls `dependency_header.hpp`
This is why the `PRIVATE`declaration probably had no effect. 
I can of course include the `3rdparty` in the main file, but Id like to find a way to avoir that...

Comment: So you don't just need to set it as a private lib, you also need to link to the library in one statement, and then in ANOTHER statement link your library to you project, the problem is that your linking the library to the project and the 3rd party to yours in the same statement